# Continue even after Fatal error: Uncaught exception

Tags: php, error-handling, google-api

I'm querying google API which has absurdly low limit of 100/day and I get:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling GET ...
```

.. and the script fails doing nothing after that point.

How do I prevent it from failing and at least save whatever data was received up to that point? I'm saving the data in an array:

```
function searchImages($service, $optParams, $query) {
  $results = $service->cse->listCse($query, $optParams);
  return $results;
}
$descriptionSearch = searchImages($customsearchService, $customsearchService_optParams, $descriptions[$i]);
foreach ($descriptionSearch->items as $item) {
  array_push($list[$item_codes[$i]], strtok($item->link,'?'));
}
```

Comment: The best option is to wrap your request within a try/catch block, so that you can handle the exception.... it's only fatal if you don't do this

Comment: So `try { foreach ... } catch (Exception $e) { echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();  }` ?

Comment: the try/catch bloc must be inserted inside your searchImages() function... share with us the content of this function

Comment: updated description to include `searchImages` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function searchImages($service, $optParams, $query) {
  try {
      $results = $service->cse->listCse($query, $optParams);
  }catch (Exception $e) {
      // should log this exception... you can use Log4PHP
      return NULL;
  }
  return $results;
}

$descriptionSearch = searchImages($customsearchService,customsearchService_optParams, $descriptions[$i]);
if (!is_null($descriptionSearch)) {
    foreach ($descriptionSearch->items as $item) {
        array_push($list[$item_codes[$i]], strtok($item->link,'?'));
    }
}
```